# Put The xml over other xml without hiding the first xml

Tags: android, xml, layout

the xml contains layout that is to be view when the button is not clicked also the overlay layout when the button is click it should becomes visibile but does not hide the original layout just trying to make that when button is clicked the the linear layout with dark back ground come over the old view just to give a blurry effet
**Firts Xml that should be override**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="LinearlayoutActions"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout style="@style/GroupStyle" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvpage"
                    style="@style/AppNameStyle"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#312435"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llfav"
                style="@style/FooterLayoutStyle" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/notification" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv2"
                    style="@style/FooterButtonStyle"
                    android:text="Favourite" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llhome"
                style="@style/FooterLayoutStyle" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/home" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv3"
                    style="@style/FooterButtonStyle"
                    android:text="Home" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lllock"
                style="@style/FooterLayoutStyle" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/lock" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv4"
                    style="@style/FooterButtonStyle"
                    android:text="Lock" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/overlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/darkgraytransparent"
visibility="gone" >
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**My Java class contains this code**

```
    LinearLayout lloverlay;
Button btn;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);
lloverlay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.overlay);
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

btn.setOnClickListner(new OnClickListner){

onClick (View v){
lloverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
});
}
```

**[before button click the app looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG6uO.png)**

**[After the button click the app looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHDwX.png)**

Comment: You could inflate a view programmatically with transparent background and make it as large as the whole screen

Comment: Hey I inflated the xmls but the problem was that when the button was clicked the second xml overirdes the first xml but it also mean while hides the first xml.

Comment: @champion, your code is working good for me. Please check it again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, this may help you.

My sample code:

```
  <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

//Your first  xml (main) layout  here
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#FFD6DD"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Sample Slide"
                        android:textColor="#FF5656"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

//Your second xml (overlay) layout here. this may be relative/linear layout
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/overlay"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#88888888"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

On button click, change the visiblity of overlay layout.

According to your code :

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

//Your first  xml (main) layout  here
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="LinearlayoutActions"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout style="@style/GroupStyle" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvpage"
                    style="@style/AppNameStyle"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#312435"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llfav"
                style="@style/FooterLayoutStyle" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/notification" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv2"
                    style="@style/FooterButtonStyle"
                    android:text="Favourite" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llhome"
                style="@style/FooterLayoutStyle" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/home" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv3"
                    style="@style/FooterButtonStyle"
                    android:text="Home" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lllock"
                style="@style/FooterLayoutStyle" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/lock" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv4"
                    style="@style/FooterButtonStyle"
                    android:text="Lock" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

//Your second xml (overlay) layout here. this may be relative/linear layout


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llOverLay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/darkgraytransparent" >
</LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: yes, output like this: before overlay [before](http://screencast.com/t/GcMj1USrjPC) and after overlay [after](http://screencast.com/t/7wXC79sWYN)

Comment: yes according to my code, the parent layout should be a relative layout. In your coding, you are using seperate xml's for main content and overlay, I am using single xml. In my code Assume "layout" layout is same as your first xml main linear layout and assume "overlay" layout is same as your second xml main linear layout. Here i am using relative layout for overlay layout, but you can use linear layout also.

Comment: @champion update my coding.. please check it. I hope you got me.

Comment: ok I think you are trying to say that the single xml contains the same code 2 times right and when the button get clicked the 1 layout, that is a copy of second one and both are present in same xml, gets visibility gone and other layout visibilty become visible

Comment: I think you missed the relative layout closing tag

Comment: No, one Relative code is ended with "</RelativeLayout>" and another one is ended with this "/>"

Comment: <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/overlay"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#88888888"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone" />              BY putting this code and doing the visibility= visible hides the old layout and shows itself only

Comment: heloo when i am programatically changing the visibility like this:      lloverlay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.overlay);                                      and on button click doing this                                                                                                                                                        
      Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, "sada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      lloverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: here the toast gets visible on button click but the relative layout does not gets visible where as when the visibilty from xml is changed it shoe the color of relative layout on my whole activity page

Comment: @champion could you please share your Activity/Fragment code fully?

Answer (score 0):

Use FrameLayout as first xml and set visibility `android:visibility="gone"` and then use second.xml. after clicking the button make that frameLayout to Visible i.e. `android:visibility="visible"`.

Comment: I did'nt got any solution yet. please the the images that will make clear to u what i am asking